# Android: How to detect when multiple http requests complete

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this app that onResume() creates five fragments. Each fragment then opens a http connection to download an XML file. This is done using an AsyncTask. In the async tasks onPostExecute() the XML file is processed and the result rendered in a tab.

I'm trying to figure out how to display a "Loading..." screen that is removed when the last fragments XML file is processed.

I've looked at onPreExecute() to setup a ProgressDialog but I only want to do it once...

I could create a counter that was incremented when my fragment was created and... decremented(?) when the XML processing completes and then just wait for it to reach zero. But that's not really very elegant. Also I would like to make it "future proof" so that I don't have to change the code when I add tab #6.

Please help...

Comment: Why not let each Async task create the fragment once it had downloaded the XML?

Comment: I could do that but it still doesn't solve my original problem of creating a splash/loading screen. Also the AsyncTask is called from the fragments onResume()

Comment: Actually got it working. Dunno if it's the most elegant solution. Created a HashMap<Integer, Boolean>. Load it with false for each id and when each fragment completes flip the flag for that fragment and check if all flags are set and true.